# rails server won't run, I am getting an error with railties, spring, and a couple other 'require' errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

here's the error I get:

```
iMac:raddit Keith$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-07-09 10:35:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-09 10:35:43] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
Exiting
/Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:459:in `tcp_server_sockets'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:133:in `listen'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:114:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Keith/Documents/0Coding/Rails/raddit/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/Keith/Documents/0Coding/Rails/raddit/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Keith/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Keith/Documents/0Coding/rails/raddit/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have tried updating all gems, rails, ruby, specific gems listed here (spring, railties, etc), i bundle installed, rake db:migrate.. I'm not too adept at rails, so any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

++kb

Comment: try `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: this worked! binding the rails server to 0.0.0.0 was the solution. I think it has something to do with the MAMP stack I was using. I must have changed settings getting that set up. Thank you! (I'd mark this as the answer, but it's just a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/hosts file, it's default configuration for 'localhost' needs to be -

if not try with this.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```